How to run the application from external flash in RiverDI STM32U5A9 STM32Qube IDE
I have been facing an issue, where I want to update the firmware through OTA in my RiverDI 5inch display module (Riverdi_50STM32U5A9) and boot the new firmware. The elf file is of size 4MB+ and I cant directly store the same in the internal flash memory.  The device is using internal flash for storing the major firmware elf and using external flash memory for storing the touchgfx image files. I cant figure out how to store my 4MB of elf file that I have and split it into separate sections as the STM32programmer does. Please pour your ideas for this situation.
Thanks & Regards
I tried to write into external flash after setting the memory mapped mode, but the write was unsuccessful. So I am stuck there aswell.

You should ask your last paragraph as a separate question (and include a lot more details about it). For the first part, it sounds like you need to implement a bootloader to receive updates and program them into flash.

@pmacfarlane - no OP does not know what is this elf file he has and how it is related to flash image.


The elf file is of size 4MB+ and I cant directly store the same in the
internal flash memory.

You need to extract sections which sits in FLASH and generate the .bin file which you will store in Flash memory.

I cant figure out how to store my 4MB of elf file that I have and
split it into separate sections as the STM32programmer does. Please
pour your ideas for this situation.

As you use STMCubeIDE it can do the hard work for ya.
Right click on priject -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings  and then

Find the generated .bin file and use this one.
